# One curve driven by anther?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to have multiple curves that are all driven by a single curve in terms of control vertices. Is there a way to have a curves shape dictated by another curve?

Comment: You can use a curve as taper object in a different curve. The control are on the geometry section of the curve in the properties window. See if this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8687/how-to-vary-the-thickness-of-a-bezier-curve/8691#8691

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58815 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157349

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not trying to control the taper, I'm trying to control the shape of multiple curves with one set of control vertices.

Comment: You can use hooks.

Comment: It would help if you edit your question and add an image with a sketch of what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and explain it a little better. What I'm trying to achieve is a series of objects each which has array and curve modifiers. I want the objects all to follow the same curve shape but I want freedom to change the "radius" value on the control vertex independently for each object. In my mind it seemed like the way to go about it would be to have multiple curves which follow a "parent" curve but can have their radius values edited separately.

Comment: please edit your question and add this information to it.